# Код ничего не выводит, помогите пожалуйста исправить его

Tags: python

На 2 фото прикрепил какое задание мне нужно выполнить, а так же код, который я написал. Что в нем нужно исправить, чтобы он работал? Сейчас он не выводит вообще ничего.

```
for n in range (1,1000):
    s='3'+'5'*n
    while '25' in s or '355' in s or '555' in s:
        if '25' in s:
            s=s.replace('25','32',1)
        if '355' in s:
            s=s.replace('355','25',1)
        if '555' in s:
            s=s.replace('555','3',1)
    for x in s:
        sum=0
        sum+=int(x)
    if sum/(sum//2)==2:
        print(n)
        break
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Описание задачи и свой код приведите форматированным текстом. Картинки могут понадобиться только как средство пояснения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Последние два блока кода нужно сдвинуть на отступ вперед, в цикл. `sum = 0` тоже.
2. Метод определения простоты числа явно неверен. Замените его на нормальный.

Вот исправленный, дополненный и приведенный ко всем стандартам код:

```
# Функция проверки простоты числа
def is_prime(a):
    if a % 2 == 0:
        return a == 2
    d = 3
    while d * d <= a and a % d != 0:
        d += 2
    return d * d > a

# Основной код
s = '355555'
for _ in range (1, 1000):
    while any([i in s for i in ['25', '355', '555']]):
        if '25' in s:
            s = s.replace('25', '32', 1)
        if '355' in s:
            s = s.replace('355', '25', 1)
        if '555' in s:
            s = s.replace('555', '3', 1)
    summa = sum([int(i) for i in list(s)])
    if is_prime(summa): print(summa)
```

`sum` использовать в качестве переменной — плохая идея, это имя встроенной функции python.

*P.S.* Почитайте PEP8. Стиль кода оставляет желать лучшего.

Comment: Я добавил код, подскажите пожалуйста как правильно написать

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B5+%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE

Comment: @Абонент, если вам помог мой ответ, поставьте, пожалуйста, галочку слева от вопроса, чтобы отметить его как принятый.